# mapping items and flattening into single array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I have a reactjs function that simply queries a pouchDB document, gets 7 records and then I'm trying to flatten those records in order to store in state. The problem is that, right now when I console.log `docCalories` I get this:

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: {caloriesBurned: "5345", createdAt: "2020-03-28T05:15:24.369Z"}
  1: {caloriesBurned: "1234", createdAt: "2020-03-28T10:39:16.901Z"} 
  2: {caloriesBurned: "1122", createdAt: "2020-03-28T10:32:03.100Z"}
  3: {caloriesBurned: "1234", createdAt: "2020-03-28T05:16:54.846Z"}
  4: {caloriesBurned: "1234", createdAt: "2020-03-28T10:21:31.092Z"}
  5: {caloriesBurned: "1234", createdAt: "2020-03-28T05:08:00.791Z"}
  6: {caloriesBurned: "1234", createdAt: "2020-03-28T05:07:35.940Z"}
  length: 7__proto__: Array(0)
```

but I want to get something that looks like this:

```
map: [5345,1234,1122,1234,1234,1234,1234]
```

So basically one object that contains the 7 numbers from each doc's caloriesBurned value

What am I doing wrong here and how can I properly put these into one array/object?

```
      setMax = () => {
    this.state.caloriesDB.db.find({
      selector: {
        $and: [
          {_id: {"$gte": null}},
          {caloriesBurned: {$exists: true}},
          {createdAt: {$exists: true}}
        ]
      },
      fields: ['caloriesBurned', 'createdAt'],
      sort: [{'_id':'desc'}],
      limit: 7
    }).then(result => {

      const newDocs = result.docs;
      const docCalories = newDocs.map((caloriesBurned) => caloriesBurned)

      console.log('this is map');
      console.log(docCalories);

    }).catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: `const result = data.map(x => +x.caloriesBurned)`

Comment: So, the issue hers is that `docCalories` contains array of strings instead of array of numbers?

Comment: @Dupocas your result gives me what I want in my console, but for some reason after I do ```this.setState({maxCalories: docCalories})``` when I replace a line in my file ```data:[5345,1234,1122,1234,1234,1234,1234]``` with ```data:[this.maxCalories]``` I now get NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the entire object in your map function, instead you should only send the `caloriesBurned` property.

```
const docCalories = newDocs.map((data) => data.caloriesBurned)
```

or if you like, we can destructrure data and have

```
const docCalories = newDocs.map(({caloriesBurned}) => caloriesBurned)
```

Comment: your result gives me what I want in my console, but for some reason after I do this.setState({maxCalories: docCalories}) when I replace a line in my file data:[5345,1234,1122,1234,1234,1234,1234] with data:[this.maxCalories] I now get NaN

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. You could ask another question and I'll try to help you there.

Comment: that would be great thank you. It's here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60920394/using-state-value-in-state-data-for-apex-charts-within-react-app

Answer (score 0):

What Dupocas has written in the comments is correct.

`newDocs` is a list of objects and with this code:

```
const docCalories = newDocs.map((caloriesBurned) => caloriesBurned)
```

you will just get another list that is just like `newDocs`. What you want to return from the map function is a specific key, so try:

```
const docCalories = newDocs.map(doc => doc.caloriesBurned)
```

Answer (score 0):

considering `docCalories` value in m2 by creating map, you can do something like this -

```
const m2 = new Map(Object.entries([{
        0: {
            caloriesBurned: "5345",
            createdAt: "2020-03-28T05:15:24.369Z"
        }
    },
    {
        1: {
            caloriesBurned: "1234",
            createdAt: "2020-03-28T10:39:16.901Z"
        }
    },
    {
        2: {
            caloriesBurned: "1122",
            createdAt: "2020-03-28T10:32:03.100Z"
        }
    },
    {
        3: {
            caloriesBurned: "1234",
            createdAt: "2020-03-28T05:16:54.846Z"
        }
    },
    {
        4: {
            caloriesBurned: "1234",
            createdAt: "2020-03-28T10:21:31.092Z"
        }
    },
    {
        5: {
            caloriesBurned: "1234",
            createdAt: "2020-03-28T05:08:00.791Z"
        }
    },
    {
        6: {
            caloriesBurned: "1234",
            createdAt: "2020-03-28T05:07:35.940Z"
        }
    }
]))
var store = [];

Array.from(m2).map(([key, value]) => store.push(value[key].caloriesBurned));
console.log(store);
```