# using state value in state data for apex charts within react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I've reduced/mapped my database query to return an array like this `docCalories: [123,456,789,345,234,678,234]` which is how I want it

I'm setting this to a state variable called `maxCalories` at the end of that function where I'm mapping.

The problem is, I'm trying to use the value of maxCalories as another state variable which is used for an apex-chart but it's not working and I'm wondering if it's because my chart `series` value is in the state along with `maxCalories` while the function that maps and sets maxCalories is done in a componentDidMount function. The chart is rendered on page load so I'm just trying to figure out how I can use maxCalories in the state data for my chart.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";
import { StyleSheet, css } from 'aphrodite/no-important';

import DB from '../../db';
import * as moment from 'moment';



class TrendsComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentDate: new Date(),
      maxCalories: '',
      caloriesDB: new DB('calorie-records'),
      calorieElements: null,
      series: [
        {
          name: "Trend (tracked)",
          data: [this.maxCalories]
        }
      ]

    };
  }

   componentWillMount(){

        this.fetchData();
        this.getMax();

        console.log('this is the mounted max calories');
        console.log(this.state.maxCalories);
    }

    fetchData = () => {
        this.setState({
            calorieElements: null,
        });
        this.state.caloriesDB.db.allDocs({
            include_docs: true,
        }).then(result => {
            const rows = result.rows;
            console.log('this is a row');
            console.log(result);
            this.setState({
                calorieElements: rows.map(row => row.doc),
            });
            console.log(this.state.calorieElements);
        }).catch((err) =>{
            console.log(err);
        });
      }

      getMax = () => {

        this.state.caloriesDB.db.createIndex({
          index: {
            fields: ['_id','caloriesBurned', 'createdAt']
          }
        }).then(result => {
          console.log(result);
          this.setMax();

       }).catch((err) =>{
          console.log(err);
        });
      }

      setMax = () => {
        this.state.caloriesDB.db.find({
          selector: {
            $and: [
              {_id: {"$gte": null}},
              {caloriesBurned: {$exists: true}},
              {createdAt: {$exists: true}}
            ]
          },
          fields: ['caloriesBurned', 'createdAt'],
          sort: [{'_id':'desc'}],
          limit: 7
        }).then(result => {

          const newDocs = result.docs;
          const docCalories = newDocs.map(x => +x.caloriesBurned);

          console.log('this is map');
          console.log(docCalories);

          this.setState({
            maxCalories: docCalories
          });

          console.log('this is maxCalories FINAL');
          console.log(this.state.maxCalories);

        }).catch((err) =>{
          console.log(err);
        });
      }

  render() {

    return (

          <div className="mixed-chart">

            <Chart

              options={this.state.options}
              series={this.state.series}
              type="area"
              stacked="true"
              width="700"
            />
          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrendsComponent;
```

rea

Comment: you should load your initial data on componentDidMount. You don't have to set `calorieElements` to null at the beginning because by updating your state inside the promise you're overriding that piece of the state. Now, what's the problem with `maxCalories`?

Comment: so the issue is that if I console.log(this.state.maxcalories) then it does eventually show in console as I want it but they way I use it in the series data for my chart, it just renders as NaN

Comment: Aaaah, I see...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so the issue is that you're not updating your series, down in your render method you're using `this.state.series`, but when you're updating `maxCalories` you're not doing it right.

```
  setMax = () => {
    this.state.caloriesDB.db.find({
      selector: {
        $and: [
          {_id: {"$gte": null}},
          {caloriesBurned: {$exists: true}},
          {createdAt: {$exists: true}}
        ]
      },
      fields: ['caloriesBurned', 'createdAt'],
      sort: [{'_id':'desc'}],
      limit: 7
    }).then(result => {
      const newDocs = result.docs;
      const docCalories = newDocs.map(x => +x.caloriesBurned);

      console.log('this is map');
      console.log(docCalories);

      //This is how you should do it, to update your state correctly
      this.setState({
        series: [{
          name: "Trend (tracked)",
          data: docCalories
        }]
      });

      console.log('this is maxCalories FINAL');
      console.log(this.state.maxCalories);

    }).catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

now, on your constructor, you might want to initialize it differently

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    //rest of your state
    series: [
      {
        name: "Trend (tracked)",
        data: []//<- Initialized as an empty array because initially there's no value
      }
    ]
```

I think this should solve your problem and avoid any issues

Comment: YES!!! You are AWESOME! I needed you a few days ago haha, I've had so many issues with charting data here but I've slowly made it through. I was truly stuck here though, I appreciate all of your help!